# Input type number bug with safai and iphone browser?

Tags: html, ios, mobile, safari, webkit

I have a input field in which the input is going to be a number. Hence, I am defining the input type to be number. See below:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  Some Number Input
  <input type="number" size="100"/>
</body>
</html>
```

On a desktop, When I open this on chrome, and enter "4111111111111111", the number stays the same, but when I open in Safari, it converts it to "4111111111111110",On iOS devices it does the exact same thing as well. Works fine in Android devices, where it does not change the number.
If you swap last number to say 5 or more, it will make it a "20" at the end instead of "10".

The reason I am putting type="number", is because I want the device to pull up a keyboard with number, which it does but looks like iOS device has limitation on 15 chars?

Any help would be appreciated.